# How can I retrieve the build parameters used when a build was triggered in VSTS (using the REST API)?

Tags: rest, api, build, azure-devops

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve the build parameters that were used when a build was triggered in VSTS (using the REST API).

I'm successfully retrieving builds using the following query:

https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/build/builds

... but in the response I can't find the parameters that were used.

Comment: Have you checked `.properties` and `.triggerInfo`?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the parameter key value pairs in the 'parameters' property